# Output of sub-processes in DOS batch script not visible in Apache

Tags: apache, batch-file

I'm running Apache 2.2 (launched via console) on Vista. I have simple batch script in cgi-bin. Unfortunately, Apache does not seem to serve any content generated by sub-processes.

For example, given the following script:

```
@echo off
echo Content-Type: text/html
echo.
echo Visible in browser
cmd /c echo Hidden from browser
echo End of script
```

All three lines of text will appear in the console if executed directly from a command prompt. However the middle line ("Hidden from browser") will not appear if the script is launched from Apache.

This script is just illustrative -- I'm actually using the batch file to launch a number of separate console based applications (not cmd.exe)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: using batch is what you are doing wrong. Use Perl,PHP,Ruby, or Python (even vbscript - asp )

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this, over at : 
[Pipe Java output to calling script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818389/pipe-java-output-to-calling-script)

FWIW, all of this `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\cgi-bin\testbat.bat`'s `echo` output appears in both the command window and the served webpage :

```
@echo off
  rem  This works in Wampserver's Apache cgi-bin...
  rem     http://localhost/cgi-bin/testbat.bat
echo Content-Type: text/html
echo.
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^</head^>^<body^>
echo ^<H1^>Hello world!!!^</H1^>
echo ^<PRE^>
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN (`dir`) do echo %%i
echo ^</PRE^>
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN (`cmd /c echo NOT hidden!`) do echo %%i
echo ^</body^>^</html^>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many more details aside, this behavior happens when `cmd` is invoked via `CreateProcess()` with `DETACHED_PROCESS`, which is what Apache does in `ap_cgi_build_command()` through `apr_proc_create()` (reference to Apache 2.2.25 source code).

For some reason, the child processes from `cmd` are *also* spawned detached. This also happens in other situations (e.g., invoking `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run()` in the same context) which might or might not involve `cmd` in the background.

Unrelated lesson learned: if `CreateObject(DETACHED_PROCESS)` and I/O redirection (`STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`) are mixed together, results might be surprising.

As far as I know, there is no solution other than avoiding batch, WSH and others. The `httpd` team might look into this for a workaround in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It would work from the command line as expected but what are the applications that you are trying to run in apache's cgi-bin? I have not heard of Apache's cgi-bin being a batch file...and that could be a potential exploit...maybe the permissions are not set for the batch file...or that there is no plugin available for Apache to actually execute a batch file, think of the mod handlers used for ssl (secure sockets layer)...like this as an example found in Apache's config file...***httpd.conf***

```
<LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so>
....
<if mod_ssl>
....
</if>
```

This would explain why you cannot run a batch file as a cgi-bin script...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to redirect the output to your STDOUT. I haven't tried it on Windows machine, but you could try

```
cmd /c echo Hidden from browser >&1
```

or redirect it to a temp file and call `type` on the file.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel echo in your own process does, but what about the one that run in subprocess?