# Pipe Java output to calling script

Tags: java, apache, servlets, batch-file

My goal is to run a CGI on apache webserver.  My CGI is written in Java.  I'm using a batch file (later could be a perl script) that kicks off the java CGI that does all the business.

The batch file works and kicks off the Java CGI.  The java program by itself works.  BUT nothing is sent back to the browser from my java code.  I'm doing simple System.out.println to send stuff to the browser.  I'm using [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-1997/jw-01-cgiscripts.html?page=1) as a reference

### My batch file

```
    echo Content-Type: text/html
    echo.
    echo ^<html^>^<head^>^</head^>^<body^>
    echo Hello world!!!
    java -cp My.jar MyClass
    echo ^</body^>^</html^>
```

### My Java File

```
    new File("C:\\wamp\\www\\cgi-bin\\" + new Date().getTime()).mkdir();
    System.out.println("<b>Hello world from Java</b>");
```

Side Note - I'm doing this because (not using servlet container etc) my task is 2 to 3 minutes long and I don't want to block the servlet.  At the same time, I need to update the user on progress of the task.  This is non-public facing and I dont want to make it too complicated, by using JMS, ajax etc to run it inside container...

Comment: Why dont use Servlet 3.0 and Async support?

Comment: I thought of that.  Havent used it, so will need to look into it.  But for now, I'm looking for a quick setup/solution, to get me going and running it directly under apache as a CGI gives me that.

Comment: I'm intrigued, are you trying this kind of thing? http://www.chipple.net/mt/2008/01/08_005220.php ... see this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170047/output-of-sub-processes-in-dos-batch-script-not-visible-in-apache  .. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=796949

Comment: Found the answer in the 2nd link you provided.  "using batch is what you are doing wrong. Use Perl,PHP,Ruby, or Python (even vbscript - asp ) ".  I used Perl and that did it.  Now add an answer so I can accept it.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered if,
 if `java -cp My.jar MyClass` displays what it should as an individual command, but doesn't work in the batch, maybe there would be a workaround with `for /f` ...

```
@echo off
  rem  This works in Wampserver's Apache cgi-bin...
  rem     http://localhost/cgi-bin/testbat.bat
echo Content-Type: text/html
echo.
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^</head^>^<body^>
echo ^<H1^>Hello world!!!^</H1^>
echo ^<PRE^>
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN (`dir`) do echo %%i
echo ^</PRE^>
echo ^</body^>^</html^>
```

Anyhow, glad you solved the problem anyway :)
Cheers