# Difficulty with Windows batch file executing command line program through Apache/PHP and web browser

Tags: php, windows, apache, batch-file

I've written a Windows batch file that I would like PHP to call at certain times. This batch file currently has only two lines, the first echoing some text to a file (for debugging), and a call to a third-party command line program.

This batch file runs just fine when double-clicked -- the text file is created and the command line program runs. When calling it as a scheduled task, it also runs just fine. When I use the command line to execute the PHP script which calls the batch file, that works fine too. It's only when I try to load that same PHP page in the *browser* (which is my ultimate goal) that I encounter trouble. Then, the text file is created, but the command line program does not run.

Along the way, I've set Apache to run as my user account, so (I don't think) this is an issue of privileges.

Any ideas why this script doesn't work through a browser, but seemingly does everywhere else?

Comment: So, a lot of hunting later, I'm learning that the issue is that the command line program is ran in the background session used by Windows services, since Apache is ran as a service. When Apache is started in the command line, the script works like expected. Looks like I've got some re-thinking to do.

Comment: For anyone who might Google this later -- my solution was to switch from Wamp to Xampp. The latter doesn't require running Apache as a service, and therefore worked fine. Less than ideal but still a solution.

Comment: Because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26361866/259543.